# Problem with negative numbers in setDate() method of Date() object

Tags: javascript

Doing the calendar and drawing previous month days i tried to do it in the loop where i use setDate() method which has some negative numbers as input. And what  i see:

```
let testt = new Date();   //today 1 Feb 2019
    testt.setDate(0);
    console.log( testt.getDate());
    testt.setDate(1);
    console.log( 'after reset='+testt.getDate());

    testt.setDate(-1);
    console.log( testt.getDate());
    testt.setDate(1);
    console.log( 'after reset='+testt.getDate());

    testt.setDate(-2);
    console.log( testt.getDate());
    testt.setDate(1);
    console.log( 'after reset='+testt.getDate());

    testt.setDate(-3);
    console.log( testt.getDate());
    testt.setDate(1);
    console.log( 'after reset='+testt.getDate());

    testt.setDate(-4);
    console.log( testt.getDate());
    testt.setDate(1);
    console.log( 'after reset='+testt.getDate());
```

And what i see in console:

```
31
"after reset=1"
30
"after reset=1"
28
"after reset=1"
28
"after reset=1"
26
"after reset=1"
```

I expect the dates will be changed synchronously. And in the console i will see 31,30,29,28,27 dates
How to fix that?

Comment: Could you elaborate? what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I expect 31,30,29,28 .. dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not resetting the date. Output the full date object and you'll see that you're changing months every time. That's because setDate() is relative to the current month in the object. You'd have to completely reset the date for your expected output.